# Did you forget to register or load this tag? Django

Tags: django

[image]

> Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I was watching the django tutorial in udemy, and I follow the same step as the professor did. The error came out with the following error:

> Invalid block tag on line 9: "url"app4:other". Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: adding space after % sign doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Spaces are important!

You don't have a space between the tag name `url` and the parameter `'app4:other'`, so Django interprets it as one token. It's also customary to use spaces after the opening tag and before the closing tag, to increase readability, so you'd get:

```
{% url 'app4:other' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what i did was use the template tag loader and it worked, just append the tag {% load static %} on top of the <! DOCTYPE HTML> it should work from there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me thanks @knbk

Spaces are important!

You don't have a space between the tag name url and the parameter 'app4:other', so Django interprets it as one token. It's also customary to use spaces after the opening tag and before the closing tag, to increase readability, so you'd get:

{% url 'app4:other' %}